# Parsing JSON Payload in Vertica

Tags: json, vertica

I am using Vertica DB (and DBeaver as SQL Editor)  - I am new to both tools.

I have a **view** with multiple columns:

```
someint | xyz   | c         | json 
5       | 1542  | none      | {"range":23, "rm": 51, "spx": 30}
5       | 1442  | none      | {"range":24, "rm": 50, "spx": 3 }
3       | 1462  | none      | {"range":24, "rm": 50, "spx": 30}

(int)   | (int) | (Varchar) | (Long Varchar)
```

I want to create another view (or for the beginning, just be able to query it properly) of the above, *but with the "json" column separated into the individual fields/columns* "range", "rm" and "spx".

I imagine the output of the query / the new view to be something like the following:

```
someint | xyz   | c    | range | rm | spx 
5       | 1542  | none | 23    | 51 | 30 
5       | 1442  | none | 24    | 50 | 3 
....
```

So far I have not been able to even query the "range" for example.

Hence my questions:

1. How can I separate the json column key-value structure into individual columns (in a query output)?
2. How can I transfer the desired output into a new view in Vertica?

I haven't found much help in the documentation as the procedure there is to load json text files from a drive or operate on tables, which I cannot do as I only have access to a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution, so for anyone else encountering this problem:

```
SELECT a, xyza, cont,
MAPLOOKUP(MapJSONExtractor(json), 'range') AS range,
MAPLOOKUP(MapJSONExtractor(json), 'rm') AS rm,
MAPLOOKUP(MapJSONExtractor(json), 'spx') AS spx
FROM test;
```